# Как передать параметр в функцию views из urls.py. Django

Tags: python, django, views, django-urls

Я использую дополнительный параметр в функции представления, для определения уровня задания.
Столкнулась с проблемой передачи того самого параметра в функцию.
В зависимости от сложности я формирую соответствующее имя для перехода к заданию. Потом по имени уже в urls хочу передавать соответствующий параметр, чтобу для всех типовых заданий использовать одну функцию с учетом сложности.

При этом некоторые задания не имеют нескольких уровней сложности. Поэтому указывать доп. параметр в шаблоне не совсем удобно, т.к. его придется считывать для всех функций. Можно ли передать параметр прямо из файла urls.py?

Для примера прикладываю task5, в который передается параметр rotation. Имя для перехода к другой задаче храню в переменной transition.

views.py:

```
def task5(rotation, request):
    submitbutton = request.POST.get("submit")
    task = Testtask.objects.get(slug="task5")
    flag1 = True
    flag2 = 0
    transition = "test1/task3"
    if rotation == 1:
        n = str(random.randint(201,299))
    elif rotation == 2:
        n = str(random.randint(101,199))
    else:
        n = str(random.randint(11, 99))
    answer = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        n = int(request.POST.get("param_n"))
        user_ans = request.POST.get("user_ans")
        if user_ans==to_bin([n])[0]:
            if rotation == 1 or rotation == 2:
                answer = "Все верно, вернемся к вопросу посложнее"
                flag1 = False
                flag2 = 4
            else:
                answer = "Все верно, для закрепления реши более сложный вариант"
                flag1 = False
                flag2 = 5
                transition = "test1/task5a"
        else:
            if rotation == 1:
                answer = "Ошибочка! Повтори теорию и мы предложим вариант попроще."
                flag1 = False
                flag2 = 1
                transition = "test1/task5b"
            elif rotation == 2:
                answer = "Ошибочка! Стоит более внимательно изучить теорию, давай еще раз, только проще"
                flag1 = False
                flag2 = 1
                transition = "test1/task5с"
            else:
                answer = "Снова промах! Повтори теорию еще раз и реши задание попроще. Ты сможешь вернуться сюда позже."
                flag1 = False
                flag2 = 2
                transition = "test1/task2a"
    context = {'task': task, 'submitbutton': submitbutton, 'flag1': flag1, 'flag2': flag2, 'transition': transition,
               'n': n, 'answer': answer}
    return render(request, 'test1/universal.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', test1_main, name='test1'),
    path('task3', task3, name='test1/task3'),
    path('task4', task4, name='test1/task4'),
    path('task5', task5, name='test1/task5a'),
    path('task5', task5, name='test1/task5b'),
    path('task5', task5, name='test1/task5c'),
]
```

Шаблон universal.html

```
{%if flag2 == 1 %}
                    <p>{{answer}}</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#" role="button">Повторить теорию</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{%url transition%}" role="button">Упростить вариант</a>
```

Пробовала следующее решение, но выдало ошибку `task5() got multiple values for argument 'rotation'`.
urls.py

```
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', test1_main, name='test1'),
    path('task3', task3, name='test1/task3'),
    path('task4', task4, name='test1/task4'),
    path('task5', task5, {'rotation': 1}, name='test1/task5a'),
    path('task5', task5, {'rotation': 2}, name='test1/task5b'),
    path('task5', task5, {'rotation': 3}, name='test1/task5c'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле все оказалось намного проще, чем я думала. Решение, которое я пробовала, но мне выдавало ошибку:

```
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', test1_main, name='test1'),
    path('task3', task3, name='test1/task3'),
    path('task4', task4, name='test1/task4'),
    path('task5', task5, {'rotation': 1}, name='test1/task5a'),
    path('task5', task5, {'rotation': 2}, name='test1/task5b'),
    path('task5', task5, {'rotation': 3}, name='test1/task5c'),
]
```

Такое решение работает, если немного исправить:

В urls.py добавить обозначения каждой ротации в сам url, иначе на один url он принимает несколько представлений и не понимает что ему с этим делать:

```
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', test1_main, name='test1'),
    path('task3', task3, name='test1/task3'),
    path('task4', task4, name='test1/task4'),
    path('task5a', task5, {'rotation': 1}, name='test1/task5a'),
    path('task5b', task5, {'rotation': 2}, name='test1/task5b'),
    path('task5c', task5, {'rotation': 3}, name='test1/task5c'),
]
```

В views.py параметр rotation должен идти следом за request, этот момент не совсем поняла, но видимо так необходимо инициализировать все функции имеющие параметры кроме request (все аргументы писать после него):

```
def task5(request, rotation):
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно получать в url параметр

```
path('task5/<int:rotation>/', task5, name='task5'),
```

после в функции вы укащыаете request и rotation

```
def task5(request,rotation):
    ...
```

А в шаблоне добавьте url  в ссылку вот так:

```
<a href="{% url 'task5' rotation %}">
```

Comment: Все верно, решение простое и лаконичное, но мне не совсем подходит, т.к. я формирую url для перехода в тех же функциях в зависимости от определенного условия и подставляю потом в шаблон. Проблема в том, что при таком задании параметра как в ответе невозможно будет передать url без сформированной rotation, а такая возможность должна быть обязательно.

Comment: Не совсем понял, что конкретно тогда требется. Если вам надо иметь возможность не передавать rotation, в функции просто изначально присвойте ему значение и сделайте проверку.
def task5(request, rotation=None):
    if rotation: